# In a LoginRequiredMixin How to receive the redirect_field_name

Tags: python, django

Got this from the documentation:

```
class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

But in my `loginView(FormView)` I can not find the way to receive and use the "redirect_to" var within the `form_valid()` method to send the user back to his original section.

Actually I can receive it in the `get()` method, but I think I need it in the `form_valid()`

Please, how could I achieve this?

Comment: Django comes with [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), including a login view. It might be easier to use that rather than writing your own `LoginView`.

Comment: Yes, I used  something like this documentation example:
`url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}),`
and it works good, but I really need to customize the view to do more things like get the username, because I ask for the email to the user at the template, and stuff like these

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve `redirect_to` from `request.GET`, so in your CBV method you can use `self.request.GET.get('redirect_to')`.

Note that **it might not be safe to redirect to a url fetched from the query string**. For example, it could link to a different domain. Django has a method [`is_safe_url`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2bdc9616f469c6b303bdc2711305ce9a1abbdcb6/django/contrib/auth/views.py) that it uses to check next urls when logging in or out.

Comment: When I use the `self.request.GET` within the `form_valid()` method the resultant dictionary from `GET` is empty, I think is because after the form post there is nothing in get, or I don't know why but it is empty, any idea, documentation, or example of a login view using the `next` variable?

Comment: Looks like you figured out the problem - as you say in your answer, you need to include the value as a hidden fieild in your form.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `get` method and added the `get_context_data` instead:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Login_vw, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['next'] = self.request.GET.get('redirect_to')
        return context
```

and then in my tamplate form added this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
```

then within the `form_valid` method retrieve the "`next`" variable like this:

```
next = self.request.POST.get('next')
```

And thats it, in a brief explanation, `get_context_data` receives the next url, send it to the *template form*, and the template form sends it back to the `form_valid` method.